# The best way to get the last UTC midnight unix timestamp

Tags: ruby, unix-timestamp

I need to know the timestamp of the last midnight that happened *in London*, regardless of the timezone I run this code in.

```
require "date"
Date.today.to_time.to_i
```

seems to get the local midnight.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
year = Time.now.utc.year
month = Time.now.utc.month
day = Time.now.utc.day
Time.utc(year, month, day).to_i
```

More info: https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/Time.html#method-c-utc

Comment: You should create a single time instance `t = Time.now.utc` and extract the values from that instance: `Time.utc(t.year, t.month, t.day)`.

Answer (score 1):

Will this do what you want?

```
Time.now.utc.midnight.to_i
```

`Time.now` gets current local time, `#utc` sets it to UTC, `#midnight` sets it to the previous midnight, and `#to_i` converts it to a stamp.  Hope that helps!

https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/Time.html

Comment: Ruby does not have a built-in `midnight` method.

Answer (score 0):

Because the UNIX timestamp increases by exactly 86400 per day, you could calculate midnight via:

```
Time.now.utc.to_i / 86400 * 86400
#=> 1473984000
```

Or:

```
t = Time.now.utc.to_i
#=> 1474011313

t - t % 86400
#=> 1473984000
```

Comment: Related to #37 in http://infiniteundo.com/post/25509354022/more-falsehoods-programmers-believe-about-time

Comment: @Nakilon my answer applies to _UNIX time_. I'm not saying that every day has 86,400 seconds. If you don't believe it: `17000.times { |i| puts Time.at(i * 86400).utc }`